# mysql client connection hostname question

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045

Have a question that I can't seem to find an answer for.  I am trying to connect to a remote database.  I type in the following to my Ubuntu shell:

```
mysql -u test -h mysql.domain.com -p
```

mysql asks for my password and then outputs the following:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'test'@'externalit.domain.com' (using password: YES)
```

The problem is that I am not on externalit.  I am on a completely different host.  I think that the server I am on was cloned from externalit, but I didn't set the server up.  My question: does mysql have a conf file or other setting that may be automatically entering an incorrect hostname?  Can I change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the name that the server thinks goes with your IP address. It could be do to a DNS setting (it's trying a reverse-DNS), or something in the /etc/host file (mapping that IP to that host).

Comment: Thanks,

I thought of this and did a dig and the externalit FQDN resolves to a different IP.  If it is the case that it's just DNS output, then I guess the server admin has some work to do...

Comment: @mbcook - seeing a similar problem. I don't have an /etc/host file on my machine.. Any other thoughts on what I could try?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a protocol option:

```
mysql -u test -h mysql.domain.com --protocol=tcp -p
```

and/or try adding a port explicitly:

```
mysql -u test -h mysql.domain.com -P3306 --protocol=tcp -p
```

(see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_protocol)

Comment: Same here, for the same DNS-related issue.

Comment: Adding the protocol (even without hostname, as I am on localhost) did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure the reverse DNS on the machine you are connecting from matches the address for the user. 
If you are on a shared IP or can't control the reverse DNS then change the permissions on the user to 'test'@'%' this will allow anyone from any ip address connect as long as they have the correct username/password pair. of course this opens up some security issues.

You can prevent mysql from doing reverse lookups and then use 'test'@'123.123.123' as the user/host but unless you are on a fixed IP that could cause issues.

DC